# Chrome loads https page with yellow triangle, but shows green lock after refresh

Tags: google-chrome, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I am noticing some odd behavior with Chrome, and I am not sure why. When my site first loads, Chrome reports the, "However, this page includes other resources which are not secure" problem, with the yellow triangle icon. However, on a simple refresh of the page, the icon becomes the green lock, and the problem isn't reported anymore.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I am using Apache and mod_rewrite to handle the forcing of https connections. In case it is relevant, here are my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ELB-HealthChecker.*
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Even after googling first, I am not sure what the problem is, or if this may be a bug with Chrome itself.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Have you used something like FireBug to see what resources you're pulling into the page?  It's likely you're loading something over http, possibly from somewhere other than your domain?